# Java How to link library at runtime

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I have a java application and it needs linking some external library( actually jar file) to load at runtime. How can I do that?

Comment: Related (and probably dupe): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60764/how-should-i-load-jars-dynamically-at-runtime

Comment: http://jcloader.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not quite sure if link is the term you want to use, but in Java you typically just need to add your jar to the class path to make its classes and their methods/fields available.

If you mean you need to dynamically load a new jar into an existing class loader you'll probably need to build a custom class loader.